# isFixed not working as expected in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i am trying to round off the number upto 2 digits in jquery using isfixed. it is not wokring properly.

Example:

68.165.toFixed(2) return 68.17 which is correct, but when i write 68.175.toFixed(2) its returning 68.17 as well. However it should return 68.18.

Thanks

Comment: `isFixed` or `toFixed`? Neither are jQuery functions

Comment: toFixed is jquery function. You should learn jquery then.

Comment: No, it's a JavaScript function ~ [Number.prototype.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)